# Permissions with nodejs and express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a node.js server with express and the HTML page with some JavaScript, CSS, and all that. Some weeks ago I had a requirement to add images to the page, I receive the name of the image and I have to show it, also I know the directory where it is stored. The problem is that, when I was testing, I added an image to that folder and I show it when entering the page. Now I have added some more images, and I am trying to show them, but it does not work. The error is this:

> Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/fotos/Abstract-sony.jpg'

The image that I added before still works, but the new one does not. I gave them the same permissions, so it should not be that. The directories structure I am using is this:

```
/Images
/Server
  --app.js
  --package.json
  /node_modules
  /client
      --index.html
      /js
      /css
      /imgs
```

Yes, I have two folders with images, the one inside client gives no problem, the other one is the issue, and no, I can not simply move the images to /imgs. The server code is this:

```
const http = require("http");
const sio = require("socket.io");
const express = require("express");

const app = express();
const SioServer = http.createServer(app)

const io = sio(SioServer);
const sioPort = 3000;

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/client'))
app.use(express.static("/images/"))

io.on("connection", (socket)=>{
  console.log("IO user connected")
    socket.on('client_data', (id) => {
      var userId = id;
      socket.join(userId)
    });
    socket.on("lastImage",(msg)=>{
        console.log(msg)
        io.to("Web").emit("lastImage", msg)
    })
  });

app.get("/", (req,res)=>{
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/client/index.html')
})

//Lanzamos el servidor en el puerto 3000
SioServer.listen(sioPort,()=> {
    console.log(`Listening on ${sioPort}`)
})
```

On the web side, I have HTML with an  and a JavaScript with something like this:

```
function init() {
    image = document.getElementById("image");
    image.setAttribute("src", "/test.jpg");
}
socket.on("lastImage", (msg)=>{
    image = document.getElementById("image");
    image.setAttribute("src", "/"+msg);
})
```

With this, test.jpg shows up on the page, but whenever a message with a new image arrives, it throws the error from before. If I try to show the new images from the start, it also throws the error.

Also, the permissions of the images (yes, they are wallpapers, it is what I had in hand):

```
drwxr-xr-x 1 root vboxsf       750 jun 23 11:29 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root         196 jun  7 17:05 ..
-rwx------ 1 root vboxsf    191120 jun 23 11:29 1920x1080_1644315267727.jpeg
-rwx------ 1 root vboxsf    136744 jun 23 11:29 1920x1080_1646185285507.jpeg
-rwx------ 1 root vboxsf     50212 jun 23 11:29 1920x1080_1646185504142.jpeg
-rwx------ 1 root vboxsf     67215 jun 23 11:29 1920x1080.jpg
-rwx------ 1 root vboxsf    662321 jun 23 11:29 1920x1080.png
-rwx------ 1 root vboxsf   1489068 jun 23 11:29 2560x1600.png
-rwx------ 1 root vboxsf   2514658 jun 23 11:29 5120x28800.png
-rwx------ 1 root vboxsf   4160783 jun 23 11:29 5120x2880.jpg
-rwx------ 1 root vboxsf   4370767 jun 23 11:29 5120x2880.png
-rwx------ 1 root vboxsf   1204050 jun 23 11:29 8000x4500.png
-rwx------ 1 root vboxsf    866785 jun 23 11:29 848791.jpg
-rwx------ 1 root vboxsf    166850 jun 23 11:29 Abstract-sony.jpg
-rwx------ 1 root vboxsf    345646 jun 23 11:29 Blue_and_Yellow 01.jpg
-rwx------ 1 root vboxsf   4247411 jun 23 11:29 Carl.png
-rwx------ 1 root vboxsf    626061 jun 23 11:29 future-28.jpg
-rwx------ 1 root vboxsf   2858273 jun 23 11:29 Helado-5120x2880.png
-rwx------ 1 root vboxsf     31124 jun 23 11:29 nordic-wallpaper.jpg
-rwx------ 1 root vboxsf    242094 jun 23 11:29 Onda-1920x1080.jpg
-rwx------ 1 root vboxsf    437369 mar  6 21:04 prueba.jpg
-rwx------ 1 root vboxsf     90433 jun 23 11:29 Smite-Loki-Wallpaper-09053.jpg
-rwx------ 1 root vboxsf    258213 jun 23 11:29 t5CrPk.jpg
-rwx------ 1 root vboxsf 470336768 jun 15 10:53 test.mp4
-rwx------ 1 root vboxsf    211231 jun 23 11:29 wp3330706.jpg
```

Comment: Please post code, logs, error messages and other text as text, not as images. I assume/hope, the server doesn't have root permissions, but the images can only be read by root. You should probably read https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/linux-file-permissions-explained I would use `chown` and transfer the files/folder to the user of the server, usually `node` or `www`.

Comment: I see that you're probably using VirtualBox. Although many people think it's not critical to use `root` in a container/virtual system, I would avoid it.

Comment: yes @jabaa, I am using VirtualBox because I can not access the real server right now so I use it as a replacement and for testing. You are saying that you would avoid using a root user? I can try using another user and use chown on the project folder and the images one. Also the server is run by a sudoer but not with root, Would that still be a problem?

Comment: Why would you use a sudoer? Why not a dedicated user for the server? That's how most servers work, e.g. Apache httpd and Nginnx? Why would risk something? Create a system user without special permissions and transfer the files to this user. Remember, that often you also need `x` permissions for the directory.

Comment: Once we deploy it the server will be on a docker so since I yet do not know how permissions with docker works I went with what I thought was easier

Comment: You shouldn't use root in Docker, too. Docker works like the host system. A Linux-based Docker image works like a common Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to create a new user, node in my case, and give it the ownership of all the files and directories that the server needs to use. I used this commands:

```
sudo useradd node
sudo passwd node
sudo deluser node sudo 

sudo chown -R node /Images
sudo chown -R node /Server
```

Then you can run the server with:

> su node -c "node /Server/server.js"

With this the server will have access to just the needed files.

If you need to add new images make sure to give ownership to node.
Thanks jabaa, I followed your advice and it worked perfectly.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).